# How to increase default pods in Kubernetes from 110 to 250?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have a situation where I need to run a different versions of a product in a single AWS instance. but to do that total pod no is exceeding 110. Kubernetes is not able to take so much pod by default.

Is there any way to increase default pod to 250 so that I can run all the versions on a single instance?

Comment: see `--max-pods` (defaults to 110) option available with kubelet. https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/

Comment: Are you using AWS EKS ? I think this is implied

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `MaxPods` field in the [kubelet config file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/):

```
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: KubeletConfiguration
MaxPods: 250
```

You can then supply the config file to the kubelet binary with the `--config` flag, for example:

```sh
kubelet --config my-kubelet-config.yaml
```

Alternatively, the kubelet binary also has a `--max-pods` flag that allows you to set the value directly. However, this flag is deprecated and the use of a config file, as shown above, is recommended. See the [kubelet reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/).